# JSF security : page redirect vs. page forward

Tags: security, jsf

I'm new with JSF and I would like to understand why page redirect and page forward do not produce the same security render.

I have a JSF button which calls backing method :

```
<h:form>
    <!-- content... -->
    <p:commandButton action="#{login.play}" ... />
</h:form>
```

Login managed bean

```
public String play() {
   ...
   //forward implementation
   return "play";
}

public String play() {
   ...
   //redirect implementation
   return "play?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

My page `play.xhtml` is secured. Only roles `admin` or `user` can access it but with my first `play` method, the security constraint is not enabled, I can access. Why is it different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Security is performed on a per-request basis. A forward reuses the response of the current request for a different view. A redirect creates a brand new request whose response is used for the different view. You can easily see this by looking at the request URL in browser's address bar. In case of a forward it remains unchanged.

On an unrelated note, navigation by POST is poor practice. You should either conditionally display results in the same page, or navigate by GET using either a normal link or by a redirect after POST.

Comment: please why navigation by POST is poor practice ? Is it only for bookmark reason ? If I understand well, you advice me to use `play?faces-redirect=true` ? If not, how can manage security between my xhtml pages ? Thank you

Comment: It impacts bookmarkability, SEO, user experience, browser back/forward buttons, etc, yes. It's hard to understand the concrete functional requirement as the code isn't exactly self-documenting (play? what does that mean?), but if I guess it right, it represents a login form and you'd like to show the user home page after successful login. In that case, a redirect is definitely the way to go.